# Why is this custom form in WordPress not directing to the specified action?

Tags: php, wordpress

When submitting the following custom form in WordPress, the system sends to `index.php` instead of the php page specified in action.  Why is this happening and how can it be resolved?

Code:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/signincode.php" method="POST" id="form2">
```

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules enabled?

Comment: Did you check the html source? Also what is your 404 set up? May be any 404 returns to the home page.

Comment: Is your signincode.php located in your theme dir? If in root of your WP install use `site_url()` instead. If network install use `network_site_url()`

Comment: I think in Wordpress you'll have to have the form submit to itself because all pages are essentially index.php. Try creating a new blank page named appropriately for your form, then put all the code for the form in the signincode.php, keeping it in the folder for your theme. Then go into the admin and assign the new page you created to signincode.php. Leave the action attribute for the form blank so it submits to itself. You could use a conditional like "if($_POST['submit'])" to either process the form or display it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a paren and child theme?
Instead of bloginfo('template_url') try

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri